# Adding multiple columns of multiple tables into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with same column name I have to add the oprId column values for some specific condition on both tables.

Table 1

```
something  oprId

abc          1
qwe          2
```

Table 2

```
something  oprId

abc          2
qwe          5
```

Result should be

```
oprId
3
7
```

Comment: I think you have left out the important part of the question. Where does 3 and 7 come from?

Comment: it should be the sum of oprId 1+2 and 2+5

Comment: Ok. So you join `xyz` to `abc` and `ghj` to `qwe`? Are those values parameters to the query?

Comment: sorry,  I have edited the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @T1 table (something varchar(3), oprId int)
declare @T2 table (something varchar(3), oprId int)

insert into @T1 values ('abc', 1),('qwe', 2)
insert into @T2 values ('abc', 2),('qwe', 5)

select T1.oprId+T2.oprId as oprId
from @T1 as T1
  inner join @T2 as T2
    on T1.something = T2.something
```

Result:

```
oprId
------
3
7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(A.something,B.something) Something,
       ISNULL(A.oprId,0)ÍSNULL(B.oprId,0) oprId
FROM Table1 A
FULL JOIN Table2 B
ON A.something = B.something
```